# Is it safe to do DB read/write from a `launch` block within an onCreate of an activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

My android app is crashing in production with different exceptions like `IllegalStateException`, `SQLiteDiskIOException`, `SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException` etc when I try to access DB from a coroutine `launch`(created a new `CoroutineScope` for this like `ioCoroutineContext + SupervisorJob()`) block.

Is it healthy to do a DB access from such a `launch` block ? Adding to that, since this is the first access to DB in the app it will run db migrations if any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your actual problem is a race between the code you execute inside `launch` and code you execute on the main thread. It could be that one codepath is doing the initialization of the DB connection and another is using that connection, and the problem is that they are concurrent. It could also be that you're performing some illegal multithreaded access to the DB client.

Accessing the DB from a `launch`ed block is not an error on its own.

Comment: Would there be an issue if migration is running on one coroutine launch while I try a read/write from another ?

Comment: That definitely sounds like an issue, migrations are non-transactional updates of the database schema. You should ensure that all migrations happen before any queries on the database.

Answer (score 5):

For database operations i believe using async mode with Default or IO thread is better.

For instance i was working on a application where i was doing db sqlite operations in recyclerview bind view holder with launch mode in Main Thread as coroutines however by doing this my recycler view lagged a lot so instead of using launch i moved on to async in Default Thread for db operations which further resulted into performance improvements.

As Per answer from @MarkoTopolnik i agree with him totally and in your case might be issue is with multi threading when dealing with sqlite you need to be precise on how things are actually executed.

Comment: When you did the recylcerView fix, where did you do the await for the async or can I bind the `Deffered` object to the UI

Comment: Well in my case await was not needed i just used coroutines to set my db operations  in background thread to fix the lag issues however when using sqlite db operations with multiple threads it might cause run time crashes because of reference issues so to solve this go to your db helper class and remove db.close() from the method which you want to use with coroutines!

Comment: If you've not fully developed your app i strongly suggest you to use Realm database which is 10x better than sqlite, sqlite is undoubtedly native but in reality it sucks!

Comment: Thanks !! Will try out realm on my next app !!

Comment: OP does seem to be using `Dispatchers.IO`, though. Just extracted to the `ioCoroutineContext`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik yes exactly however IO threads are usually intended for disk read/write operations for huge database operations using Default with async is way better! also the crash he was facing is common when working with sqlite from my perspective launch mode is used to do something in UI thread so it might cause a lag, hence a parent scope of main thread with async thread as child would be much better

Comment: `Dispatchers.Default` and `Dispatchers.IO` are just two thread pools, equal in every way except in the policies on how many threads they are allowed to start. `Default` is optimized for CPU-bound work and runs up to `availableProcessors()` threads whereas `IO` is meant for blocking operations and it's an elastic thread pool that will start up to 1000 threads by default. So definitely _don't_ use `Default` for blocking network ops.

Comment: `launch` is almost exactly the same as `async` except that `async` produces a result and `launch` just completes.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Okay thanks for enlightening me! so our best guess is he is facing crash because of multithreading with sqlite as you stated in your answer.

Comment: Seems like it has things to do with the way I handle DB `IO`. I think its with the race around where my migration might not have finished before the next db access. Some of the `SQLiteDiskIOException `  and `SQLitewhiDiskFullException ` exceptions are happening in devices with < 1% disk space. (which I think I can ignore) or should i ?? Thanks guys !!